# Remove additional key generated by FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Database I have a node "mazdoors" and below this I want only a key "userid" generated for each user and below this userid only some details which user has filled by using the android app. But problem is that Firebase Database adds a another key automatically below "userid". Due to this problem I am unable to fetch data of all users simultaneously.

Here is my code and link of photo-

```
myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

myRef=firebaseDatabase.getReference("mazdoors").child(uid);
```

[image]

Comment: This depends on how you generated that data. Right now it looks like you do something like `ref.child(uid).push().setValue(...)`. If you don't want the push ID (the value starting with `-L`), you should do `ref.child(uid).setValue(...)`. If that's not it, edit your question to include the code that generates the data.

Comment: Thank you very much sir now it is working perfectly. Love from heart.

Comment: You're welcome @drd. I flagged your question as a "typo", since I don't think others in the same situation (this happens regularly) will find it.